# Mongoose virtual id fields and JSON responses

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I'm using NestJS and Mongoose. I'm simply returning document objects from the mongo database like below:

```
@Get()
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
async getCompany(@AuthUser() user: User) {
    const company = await this.companyModel.findById(user.companyId)
    this.logger.log(company)
    this.logger.log(company.id)
    return company
}
```

As Mongoose automatically creates an id field on the models, I can see the value of the id field. But id field is not returned in the response json. The response included the _id field, not the id.

What should I do to return the id fields to the client instead of _id?

Comment: Can you add your company model code to the question? Also why do you need id if you have already the same value in _id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your schema definition do something like this:

```
export const MySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
       field_name: String,
       }, { _id: true, 
       collection: 'collection_name', 
       id: true, toJSON: { 
          virtuals: true, 
          versionKey: true 
     } 
})
```

I just tested and it worked.

Comment: this solution still works for hiding additional virtual fields